# Is there a python function to get all indexes from unique values?

Tags: python-3.x, list, unique

I know there are methods like set() or np.unqiue() to get unique values from lists. But I search for a way to get the index for the value which occurs not more than one time.

example = [0,1,1,2,3,3,4]

what I looking for is
desired_index_list = [0,3,6]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know of any prebuilt solution, probably you need to create your own. There are different approaches for that, but with classical Python implementation, you can easily create a count_dict and filter those values from the original list that have count of 1.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> example = [0,1,1,2,3,3,4]
>>> counted = Counter(example)
>>> desired_index_list = [index for index, elem in enumerate(example) if counted[elem] == 1]
>>> desired_index_list
[0, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a one-liner with a list comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter
[example.index(x) for x, y in Counter(example).items() if y == 1]
```

(Using Counter, return tuples for each item (x) and its number of occurrence (y), and return the index of the item if it's count is 1).